# Decode ASCII string in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, ascii, string-decoding

Got a string in ASCII (with only ASCII value ranges for A-Z, a-z, and " "), want to decode it.

ex. "781059910132" cooresponds to "Nice "

Is there an easy way to do this in Python 3?

Comment: I doubt there's an unambiguous way to do this. You can't tell just by looking at the number sequence that it should be interpreted as [78, 105, 99, ...]. It could just as easily be [78, 10, 59, 91, ...].

Comment: Should have mentioned that my ASCII values are only for specific ranges. A-Z, 65-90, a-z, 97-122 and 32 respectively

Comment: I can think of an approach with looping with these restrictions but was wondering if there was a more pythonic way

Comment: Oh, in that case maybe there _is_ an unambiguous solution, since when you encounter a "1" then it can only mean you're about to encounter a three digit number.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to extract 3- or 2-digit combinations:

```
import re
ascii_char = '[01]?\d\d'
s = '781059910132'
''.join(map(chr, map(int, re.findall(ascii_char, s))))
#'Nice '
```

This code works even with 0-padded codes:

```
''.join(map(chr, map(int, re.findall(ascii_char, '07832078'))))
#'N N'
```